# Autocorrect/autoreplace for Linux?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, special-characters, character-set

I haven't used it much, but as I understand it macOS has a feature that lets you specify something to autocorrect. (e.g whenever I type `<<` it is replaced with `«`) Is there a package that I can install to give a similar functionality to Ubuntu? There are several special characters that I often need to type & it's a pain to have to switch keyboard layouts or memorize the unicode for them. A more typical use may be to type 'pi' and 'π' to appear.

EDIT: to clarify, I want this to work in any application, not just a terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu!   You mean, like  bash-completion package? (sudo apt-get install bash-completion)  ?

Comment: @WilliamMartens I don't think so, I need something that could automatically convert any sequence of characters into another. My boss uses macOS and even has a thing where if he types several abbreviations it expands it into a full phrase (e.g hru automatically converts to "how are you?", or something like that.

Comment: Japanese Input method offers such conversions, at the same time you get Japanese words, too. When I type << <space> the 5 candidates appear ＜＜ << 《 ≪ «, when I type PAI then I get this π immediately. I don't know if this can be handy for you.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka Thanks! I may have to pass on that because I have gotten mostly accommodated to the US intl keyboard to type in Spanish & English. But that is sort of the functionality I'm looking for. It would also be really cool if there were user-defined replacements, like if I typed '//shrug' it would automatically replace it with "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"

Comment: @KyleH, yes we have these user defined dictionary to convert any phonic imput `sudo apt install ibu-mozc` that adds Japanese characters input on any keyboard you have. But you need to know how to set this. φ(..) taking notes

Answer (score 0):

Define a [compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose). Then you should be able to do:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd><</kbd> followed by <kbd><</kbd> => «

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable) shows other combinations which are available out of the box.